# Batch replacing color with transparency

Tags: transparency, batch-processing

I have a very large number of PNG images (too many to practically do one at a time) with a bright pink background and would like to replace the background color with transparency. If this is not possible or particularly difficult, replacing the specified color with white would be useful.

I have gimp but not photoshop and am not particularly comfortable with command line, so if a  solution requires that please show each step. It'd be great to be able to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I know you said you're not comfortable with command line tools, but ImageMagick can do this:

> [Replace a Specific Color](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#replace)
>
> `convert balloon.gif  -transparent blue   balloon_trans.gif`
>
> [image] [image] [image]

Where `balloon.gif` is the source image, `-transparent` specifies that you want a transparent bg, `blue` is the color you want to replace, and `balloon_trans.gif` is the completed image.

This is under the assumption that your "bright pink" is not part of any of the images. For a little more intelligent background removal (floodfill), check out this tutorial: [Masking Simple Backgrounds (floodfill)](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#bg_remove)

This can get a little hairy and some of the options they specify there probably aren't required for what you're trying to do, so as @graphics man suggests you can add `background` to the command

---

If you can tell me what OS you're using and a sample image, I can help you with a script to automate this for many images

---

#### Specific to your situation:

First, install [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows). You may need to restart after installation for your PATH variable to be updated (I did)

Once it's installed, fire up a command prompt (Start Menu, type `cmd`, hit enter)

You need to change directories to where the images are saved. For your situation, enter the following command:

`cd C:\Users\Eric\Pictures\pngs\logos`

Now we need to make a folder to save all the images in:

`mkdir batch`

And now, the command to convert all the images:

`FOR %G IN (*.png) DO convert "%G" -transparent #FF00FF "batch\%G"`

**Note: With ImageMagick v7, use `magick` instead of `convert`, as so**

`FOR %G IN (*.png) DO magick "%G" -transparent #FF00FF "batch\%G"`

If everything went smoothly, the newly saved images should be in the batch folder you created.

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: good solution, if anyone wondering equivalent linux bash:        for file in *.png ; do  convert "${file}" -transparent '#ffcc66' "batch/${file}" ; done

Comment: For Mac this seems to be related: http://superuser.com/questions/773590/how-can-i-batch-with-imagemagick-command#

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work like Gimp does. If you have a white pixel with alpha 0.5 on top of a black pixel, and you want to remove the black color, the gray pixel will remain.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running gimp and are not wanting to go Imagemagick you might want to take a look at [David’s Batch Processor (DBP)](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~hodsond/dbp.html).  It is a plug-in for gimp for batch processing.  **Note** I have never used it nor tested it but it was something I have seen used before.  If you had Photoshop I could show you how to use the batch or action.

Comment: I have that and have used it to mass crop these images, but there does not appear to be any option to replace colors. Maybe I'm missing it though, or have an old version?

Comment: I do not know.  I'm just familiar with the plug-in because a client was using it to mass edit images and was getting an error.  As John has posted Imagemagick is a powerful option and could solve all your problems.  There site is very detailed.  Have a look http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Answer (score 3):

This worked like a charm for me:

http://photobatch.wikidot.com/action-color-to-alpha

Phatch is a Photo Batch Processor. Color to alpha action does exactly what you are looking for:

"The value of the color which should become transparent"